# How to extract data from a database to a Excel file using VisualBasic

Tags: excel, vb.net

I need to extract data from an Access DB to an Excel file using VisualBasic.
I did a routine that was good at the moment but, after a lot of tests, i discovered that doesn't extract all records! I discovered this failure when i tried to extract a db with only 1 record and the file excel was empty!!!
The part of the code for the extraction is this:

```
    For i = 1 To ds.Tables(0).Rows.Count - 1
        For j = 0 To ds.Tables(0).Columns.Count - 1
            xlWorkSheet.Cells(i + 1, j + 1) =
            ds.Tables(0).Rows(i).Item(j)
        Next
    Next
```

Thanks

Comment: I'm randomly guessing here, but if you changed the `For i = 1` to `For i = 0`, that might start the row selections from the 1st rather than the second row as you do `i + 1` later on,...

Comment: @Xabier, yes, i tried, but in the first row of the Excel file i have the titles of the columns. I i put "i = 0" it starts on the first row of the Excel file, erasing titles of the columns.

Comment: Then you could try changing `ds.Tables(0).Rows(i).Item(j)` to `ds.Tables(0).Rows(i-1).Item(j)` ? AS `Row(0)` would be the first row in the dataset,...

Comment: Why are you doing this with VBA? Excel has built in powerquery connector to Access

Comment: Check [Range.CopyFromRecordset method (Excel)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.range.copyfromrecordset)

Comment: @Xabier, thanks for your effort but the result is the same....

Comment: @horseyride, is not VBA, is VB.Net.

Comment: Remove `-1` from `For i = 1 To ds.Tables(0).Rows.Count - 1`.

Comment: Add a reference to EPPlus from NuGet. That library will make it very, very easy to write data to Excel.

Comment: @HardCode, thanks. Do you know where i can find some examples using this package?

Comment: @ShahramAlemzadeh, thans for the suggestion but it doesn't work......